# List Accounts related to Custom Object

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a custom object (Funding_Source__c) that has a master relationship with Opportunity by way of a custom field called `Related_Opportunity__c`. The opportunity that is related has a field called AccountId. I need to list Accounts and their fields by way of this `AccountId` Field, but I keep getting a schema error.

```
public with sharing class DS_ACTinFundingSource {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getACT(Id fsId) {
      Id oppId = [SELECT Id,Related_Opportunity__c FROM Funding_Source__c WHERE Id =:fsId].Related_Opportunity__c;
      Id actId = [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Opportunity__c WHERE Id =:oppId].AccountId;
        return [SELECT Id,FederalTaxID__c
              FROM Account WHERE Id = :actId];
    }
  }
```

The field AccountId is a lookup field within Opportunity object.

I keep getting

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH                                              ERRORS                                    
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\classes\DS_ACTinFundingSource.cls  Invalid type: Schema.Opportunity__c (5:18)
```